# Which microformat schema should I use for username?

Tags: schema.org, microformats

I dont know, if I can use Person > name schema for username.

I was looking on schema.org vocabulary, but not found some better choice.

`<div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">Username: <span itemprop="name">Selena</span></div>`

Answer (score 1):

No specific Property/item-type for "user" (As: `online account username` for person-X).

> The name of the item.
>   https://schema.org/name

The item is "user X" and the name of the item is `riddick2004-new` or `john-pro-1234` (Valid).

You could add URL/sameAs to give extra data about the user.

#### EXAMPLE

On **medium.com** - each author (Nickname) clickable to inner-page (Full Profile page). Optional to add: "sameAs" to give more data about the user.

```
<div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Person">
  <a title="Rihanna Profile" itemprop="url" href="mysite/Rihanna-user-profile">
    Author: <span itemprop="name">badgalriri</span>.
   <link itemprop="sameAs" href="https://www.instagram.com/badgalriri"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

If you want to add extra data/Property open issue her:
https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues